# Change background color of disabled selectbox option

Tags: html, css, background-color

Is it possible to change the background color of disabled option in a selectbox in HTML ?

I have 2 disabled item to split the choice in my box and would like to put a color in those disabled option to separate them.

Thanks

Comment: when you say "selectbox" you mean `select`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried `input[disabled]` as a css selector or `input:disabled`. Unfortunately I don't think there's a way to do this is IE without javascript.

Comment: I thought CSS couldn't handle that but it can. Great thanks. Need 5 mins to accept your answer since it was too fast :D

Comment: Keep in mind also that a `select` tag is impossible to style on mac. Apple just does its own thing. If anyone has a workaround for this I'd love you hear it

Comment: Yeah only with Safari on MAC, Firefox or Chrome on MAC seems to be working fine. Must be the browser config that override the style :S

Comment: I am not saying I endorse this, but to have a consistent dropdown look and feel you could create custom elements with html/css/javascript that simulate a dropdown, and set the value of a hidden field - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/834380/custom-dropdown-box-using-javascript-and-css for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Locrizak is right,

```
input[disabled]
```

it is called attribute selector, and you can easily style it in CSS.
If you want to be consistent with the results [you can find here](http://fjank.wordpress.com/2009/12/13/cross-browser-disabled-input-field/) a good guide.

The problem comes if you use IE6, because attribute selectors are not supported ([Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28VS.85%29.aspx#attributeselectors))

If you want to be sure that the result is cross-browser compatible, just add a new class to your element.

```
<input type="button" class="disabled"/>
```

this will work in IE6 as well.