# Styling css for <select> <option> drop down box for all browsers and Windows/OSX

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, html-select

I want to style my drop down box so that instead of using the OS's default styles, I can replace both  and  with custom background images.  Is there a solution that works in all major browsers (IE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari) and also for all OS's (Windows, OSX, Lunix).  I'm aware that OSX has their own type of drop down boxes that are particularly hard to style with css.

Comment: No, not really. This is by design as operating systems have put a ton of work into usability studies. Any "solution" is going to involve hacky `<div>` elements with tons of styling bloat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834380/custom-dropdown-box-using-javascript-and-css), I think [jqtransform](http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jqtransform/) is what you're looking for.

Scroll down the page to see a demo.  In addition to other elements, drop down boxes are there.

All the way at the bottom it says...

> Just edit the css file to customize your form, that's it.

Comment: Side note: I'm on FF8 on Win7 and whatever CSS is being used on the example page has pretty bad line-height or text alignment issues on the `<input>`s (text is riding the bottom edge). Figured I'd mention it since the question is about cross-browser/platform issues. Just make sure to test. The dropdowns look great in IE6 :)

Comment: Interesting.  I'm on FF8, Linux.  Do you have a screen-shot?  It works fine on Chromium too for me.  At the bottom of the page it says, *"We did our best to make it work on ie 6+, safari 2+, firefox 2+"*.

Comment: Here you go: http://i.stack.imgur.com/G8uQM.png The buttons look off as well (extra bottom padding) but I missed them in the screen shot.

Comment: There does appear to be a problem on `.jqTransformInputInner div input`.  Removing the 8px padding fixes it for me.  The reason for the large line heights on the form, is the large elements.  The normal render about 17px high compared to 31px for the custom.

Comment: About the buttons, there's a 4px padding on `.rowElem`, which wraps each visible row (label and field/button).  If you remove it, everything is too condensed for my tastes.  I think this is just *the look* recently.  Twitter, YouTube, GMail, and so on, are all using large inputs like this.